# Adding to a Hashmap via a method (Java)

Tags: java, methods, hashmap

So here goes. I've got two classes which are...

- **"Whats happening"** class

References Task class with tasks instance variable
TaskId which is a static int and will reference the map key and is set to 1

- **"Task"** class
  instance variables are all string and are Name, Date and Time

I'm wanting to add a method addTask which takes 3 arguments and adds a task via the **Whats happening** class. Every time a Task gets added, the Task ID should increment by 1. Here is what I have so far...

```
public void addTask(String aName, String aDate, String aTime)
{
Map<Integer, Task> tasks = new HashMap<>();
Task newtask = Task (aName,aDate, aTime);
tasks.put(TaskId,newtask);
TaskId = TaskId +1;  
}
```

However, when I create an instance of Whats happening ( called whatshappening) and try to add a task through the method , for example  **whatshappening.addTask("Take Cat to the vet","010117","1400");**

It always fails to add the task to the map!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like `tasks` is a method variable and goes out of scope once `addTask` has been called

Comment: you always create a new `tasks` map which gets forgotten / deleted / cleaned up after the method `addTask` finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entirety of your code then it's pretty obvious why:

The `Map<Integer,Task> task = new HashMap<>();` is allocated on the stack. Per memory allocation rules for most languages I can think of, going back 50 years, upon exit of function the map is released as are all its contents.

Try:

```
public class Thing {
private static Integer TaskId = 0;
public static void main(String .. args) {

     Map<Ineger,Task> tasks = addTask("myName", LocalDate.now()+"", LocalTime.now()+"")
     System.out.println(tasks);
}

private static Map<Integer,Task> addTask(String name, String date, String time) {
    Map<Integer, Task> tasks = new HashMap<>();
    Task newtask = Task (aName,aDate, aTime);
    tasks.put(TaskId,newtask);
    TaskId = TaskId +1; 
    return tasks; // crucial
}
}
```

That will work for you.

Some good programming suggestions:

1. You should really also not accept String for dates/times unless you
   must. They are much harder to work with
2. Put your static task id into
   the task class itself and when you instantiate the task, in the
   constructor assign `this.id = TaskId++`

Answer (score 0):

`tasks` is a variable that exists only during method invocation. Probably you need to put new `task` inside a global or external map.

Answer (score 0):

You're just creating an object with `Task (aName, aDate, aTime)` that will not be kept after the end of this method.
Try the following :

`Task newTask = Task (aName, aDate, aTime)`

You have to use dynamic allocation in order to "allow" your Task to live beyond the scope of your method.